# Access python files from lighhttpd

Tags: python, python-3.x, lighttpd

i've installed lighthhtpd server to execute php and python files... but when i run a .py file it popups a download windows to that file.

Here is what i've put in the cgi conf file

```
cgi.assign                 = (".py"  => "/usr/bin/python2.6",
                             ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi" )
```

Anyone knows how to fix this in order to have python files working on lighthttpd?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use lighttpd for a long time now but I think the suspect will probably be a wrong meta-type which can not be interpreted so it's downloaded. It should be `text/html` as for html and php - but don't ask me how to do it... I wandered to nginx.

Comment: do your .py files have execute permissions for the lighthhtpd process?

Comment: yes, they've permissions

Comment: I just realized we're in SO! I think this question is a better match for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your .py files inside a `cgi-bin` directory, and running them from there. If I remember correctly by default the lighttpd configuration only allows cgi scripts in `cgi-bin` directories. Please post your entire `cgi.conf` if possible.

If it works, find the snippet that looks like `$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin" { (...) }` and remove the surrounding match block.

When you download the file right now, what's inside? Is it the actual source of the Python script there, or the expected output of the execution in text? I'm guessing it's the earlier, if not please clarify.

Comment: yes, lighttpd works in a cgi dir... and the cgi.conf has no more special lines than above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments and answers... the solution was to insert at first line the following command :

```
print ("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8 \n")
```

I use python 3.1 with light... and when i set this first line in the script it printed it out correctly.

Comment: this works for me. although i swear i got python/lighttpd working before without having to do this.